# Accessing index of UICollectionViewCell from a ScrollView inside the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view, and inside the collection view cell, I have a scrollView in which I want to display some pictures.

I placed a ScrollView inside my collectionviewcell in the storyboard and initialised the ScrollView inside my `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` method as follows:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [cell viewWithTag:20];

scrollView.delegate = self;

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((cell.frame.size.width*images.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)];

scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:imagesScrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Only the first image from the `images` array should be loaded when the view is first loaded and the rest of the images need to be loaded dynamically when the user scrolls the scrollview, in the `-scrollViewDidScroll` method. However, these images depend on the index of the collectionviewcell that my scrollView is lying in.

How can I access the index of the collectionviewcell from the `-scrollViewDidScroll` method?

Also, does this seem like a viable method to achieve what I'm trying to do, or will I need to subclass UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing can be one of the solutions but you can get the `indexPath` of a `UICollectionViewCell` from its subviews too. The following code would hopefully serve your needs. Use it in your `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

```
UIView *superview = scrollView;

while (![superview isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {

    superview = superview.superview;
}

UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

NSLog(@"IndexPath: %@", indexPath);
```

Make sure you are not using a scrollView elsewhere in this viewController.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was trying to do something similar, but without first casting `superview` to `UICollectionViewCell` I kept getting an NSInvalidArgumentException. Should have thought of this.
Thanks!